# How to use Gitian to build the Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel, security, compiling

I want to use https://gitian.org/ to build the linux kernel. Has anyone done it yet? I need to build it in at least two different computers for security reasons, so I need to use gitian to make deterministic builds and compare the hashes.

I already created the base vm like said in https://github.com/devrandom/gitian-builder, now I just need to run `bin/gbuild file.yml` however I do not know how to write this file. Probably I must have lots of dependencies to build the kernel, so they must be in this file. I'm trying to compare with the bitcoin's file: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-linux.yml

Could somebody help me writing one? Would be nice to have people building it together.

**UPDATE:**

I started by doing:

```
---
name: "kernel-linux"
enable_cache: true
suites:
- "xenial"
architectures:
- "amd64"
packages:
- "fakeroot"
- "build-essential"
- "ncurses-dev"
- "xz-utils"
- "libssl-dev"
- "bc"
remotes: []
reference_datetime: "2017-06-01 00:00:00"
files:
- "linux-4.16-rc1.tar.gz"
script: |
  tar xzf linux-4.16-rc1.tar.gz
  cd linux-4.16-rc1
  sudo make -j 4 && sudo make modules_install -j 4
```

I'm having some problems making gitian work but it's already a good start. I think there's a need to remove timestamping from kernel code by tweaking some configurations (by the way, we still need to add the kernel configurations file)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is on topic. In any case, could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of traction your question will get here as a bit of research indicates it's at least a little bit too broad or unclear. It's kind of like asking "How do I configure an operating system. You might find [this useful](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.pdf) though.

Comment: I just want to build the linux kernel using gitian